# Inner join in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, inner-join

I am executing below query and query throws me an error(ERROR: syntax error at or near "inner")

Can someone help me if i am missing anything

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a where a.snapshot_date='2019-07-31'
inner join table2 b 
ON a.snapshot_date=b.snapshot_date
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` clause is out of order:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
inner join table2 b 
ON a.snapshot_date=b.snapshot_date
where a.snapshot_date='2019-07-31'
```

Edit: If you want the information from `table2` you should also add that to the `select` rather than just the stuff from `table1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
inner join table2 b 
ON a.snapshot_date=b.snapshot_date
where a.snapshot_date='2019-07-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Joins are used to specify the source, not part of the where clause

Try

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a inner join table2 b 
ON a.snapshot_date=b.snapshot_date
where a.snapshot_date='2019-07-31'
```